# Elegant way to calculate the nearest time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, graphics

I have a reference time:

`'2012-05-01 23:35:00'`

And I have a couple of more times from some table where the 'yyyy-MM-dd' date part is irrelevant but what is relevant is date part with 'HH:minute'

```
------------------------------
| ID |         Time          |
| -- |-----------------------|
| 01 | '1900-01-01 13:10:00' |
| 02 | '1900-01-01 07:01:00' |
| 03 | '1900-01-02 00:45:00' |
| 04 | '1900-01-02 18:00:00' |
------------------------------
```

I am writing a function that will return the row with the nearest time (in above example this would be ID 03), but I don't like what I am writing.

So I started to observe the problem graphically. Is there maybe a way to do this with Atan function?

Edit: I am using MSSQL server 2005

Comment: Why not just find the absolute difference? The smallest number is the closest.

Comment: That was my first guess. Lets do this in minutes. So the reference minutes are 1415. But the absolute difference between 45 and 1415 is 1370 minutes which is simply not correct since it should have been 70.
Then I got into using MOD(1440) but it got me only further away from the answer.

Comment: I believe the accepted answer.... indeed uses the absolute difference in minutes!

Comment: Yes I agree. That is why I rated this answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @reftime datetime;
set @reftime = '20120501 23:00:00';

    select TOP(1) with ties
           id, time
      from (
    select
           t.*,
           dateadd(d, -datediff(d, 0, @reftime), @reftime) reftime,
           dateadd(d, -datediff(d, 0, t.time), t.time) coltime
      from tbl t
           ) x
  order by (select min(diff)
            from 
            (select abs(datediff(ms, reftime, coltime))
             union all
             select abs(datediff(ms, reftime+1, coltime))
             union all
             select abs(datediff(ms, reftime, coltime+1))) y(diff));
```

Notes:

1. The `datediff(d, -datediff(...` patterns remove the date portion from the datetimes.
2. To handle cross-midnight scenarios, both `reftime+1` and `coltime+1` are tested in addition to just `abs(reftime-coltime)`.
3. The `ORDER BY` is performed across the minimum difference from testing it over all 3 scenarios.

Comment: Yes I overlooked 'with ties'. That is why I get two results. This is great thank you so much. I would say I love you but you could get me wrong :)